# Rails : JSON serialization circular reference error with Mongoid:Geospatial objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongodb, geospatial, circular-reference

I have an array of Mongo objects returned by a geolocation query such as :

```
@data = Record.geo_near([lng,lat], :max_distance => dist, :unit => :m, :spherical => true)
```

I'm then trying to serialize the response based on the expected format :

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json { render json: @data, :status => 200 } # Not working
    format.xml { render xml: @data, :status => 200 } # Working !
end
```

The weird thing is that everything go smoothly with XML, but I get this error with JSON :

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError in BouncesController#populars
object references itself
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867491/geokit-rails-plugin-cant-call-to-json-on-returned-geoloc-object-gives-circul) relating to the same kind of error, but the validated answer did not work for me.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is my model for which the issue is happening :

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Spacial::Document

  spacial_index :loc, :min => -180, :max => 180
  belongs_to :user

  field :text, :type => String
  field :loc, :type => Array, spacial: true
  field :accuracy, :type => Float

  def as_json(options={})
  {
  "id" => self.id,
  "text" => self.text,
  "loc" => self.loc,
  "accuracy" => self.accuracy,
  "user" => {
    "id" => self.user['_id'],
    "login" => self.user['login'],
    "role" => self.user['role']
  },
  "created_at" => self.created_at,
  "updated_at" => self.updated_at
  }
  end
end
```

Comment: I do have a temporary fix which is pretty nasty but works for the time being :

  `format.json { render json: Hash.from_xml(@data.to_xml).to_json, :status => 200 }`

Comment: Can you post an example of `@data` which causes the circular reference error in JSON?

Comment: I updated my question to provide the model. Anyway it could be linked to a compatibility issue with mongoid as I downgraded to 
**gem 'mongo', '1.4.0' |
gem "mongoid", "~> 2.4"|
gem "bson_ext", "~> 1.5"**
and everything is working without hacks for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have resolved the issue by downgrading my gems as follow :

```
gem 'mongo', '1.4.0'
gem "mongoid", "~> 2.4"
gem "bson_ext", "~> 1.5"
```

There is still the possibility to use the following hack, but it prevents you to format yourself the json output in your model.

```
format.json { render json: Hash.from_xml(@data.to_xml).to_json, :status => 200 }
```